# How to find all commits reachable from HEAD that were committed after a specific commit hash?

Tags: git

I'm trying to pull all files that have changed in git on a specific branch starting with a specific commit.

I don't care about ancestry, only that it's reachable from HEAD.

In essence, I'm trying to build a list of files that have been updated, modified, and deleted since commit X (since means in terms of date/time) so I can do things with these files.

I don't care if commit B is technically reachable from commit A.  I only care that commit B was committed after commit A and is reachable from HEAD.

Another way to think about what I'm doing is that I want to do a cp -R on every file that's been added or modified in the git repo since the date/time that a specific commit was pushed.

Currently I'm doing the following, but it doesn't look right to me:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --ancestry-path 05de9827fe31905b7ef98f3bbe331e922977de4d..master --date-order
```

Can anyone give me hints/tips on how to do this?  Everything I've read about the 2 and 3 dot notation is about excluding things based upon reachability, and this is specifically not what I want.

However, I'm also not the strongest git person so if I'm misunderstanding I'm more than happy to be educated on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible shortcut: remember that commits are *full snapshots*.  All the files that are different in the tip of `master`, vs what's in commit `A`, can be observed by a simple, single, `git diff` of commit `A` vs the tip commit of `master`.  See [Jake Worth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56433991/1256452).  This won't show files that were changed, then changed *back;* to get those, read on.

---

You're right that `--ancestry-path` does something very different:

```
...--o--A--*--*--*--*   <-- master
                /
    ...--o--o--o
```

The lower-line row of commits are not descendants of commit `A` and will be eliminated, but are ancestors of the tip of `master` and you probably want to include them.

Remember that there are *two* date-and-time-stamps in each commit.  These are *author date* and *committer date*.<sup>1</sup>  `git log --pretty=fuller` will show both time stamps for each commit.

You can use `--since` or `--min-age` to restrict a revision walk to commits whose *committer* timestamp is above some minimum value.  If you're interested in *author* dates, it's (much) harder (`git rev-list` lacks an option to make it use author dates).

> I only care that commit B was pushed after commit A and is reachable from HEAD.

There is no "pushed after" available, as there is no "pushed on" date in commits.  A commit could be made five years ago (so that its committer date is 2014) and pushed today.  (You can also fake the committer date, and of course, even if you don't fake it, it depends on the computer's clock being right.)  But in general, people don't mess with their committer timestamps, so if you trust those to be good enough, you can just use them.

All that said, you'll need to extract the committer timestamp from your commit `A` first:

```
git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%ci A
```

will retrieve the committer timestamp in an ISO-8601-ish format.  See the list of format directives in [the `git log` documentation **PRETTY FORMATS** section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) for various alternatives.  The `--since` date-parser takes many input forms.

(Pay attention to time zone issues, but I forget how Git actually deals with time zone issues.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The *author date* is meant to suggest when the change was first composed.  The committer date is meant to hold the time at which that particular commit, the one identified by the commit's hash ID, was created.  These two time stamps are initially the same, but if you rebase or `git cherry-pick` some commit, it retains its author date while getting a new (current-time) committer date at the moment of the rebase or cherry-pick copy (which also gets a new commit hash ID).

Because of all of this, if a commit was first written a month ago, but had to be revised a few times before getting committed today, it will have an author date that is one month old and a committer date of "today".  Hence it's pretty typical to find committer-date ≥ author-date.

Comment: Thank you, this gets me where I want to be.  I updated the verbiage around the quote about pushing to be more clear (I hadn't considered that has a specific meaning in git).  I have one follow up question if you wouldn't mind.  git log --since, is that since the commit date?  I couldn't find explicit documentation on it, but the wording of the man pages leads me to believe that it is

Comment: @Fred: I'm not sure what you are asking, but to be explicit, it tests "committer date stored in commit > date supplied as argument" (or maybe `>=` rather than `>`). Much of the words above are there to cover the fact that *committer date* doesn't necessarily mean "actually committed on", but usually does mean that.

Comment: thank you, that answered my question.  I've got everything working now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but "I'm trying to build a list of files that have been updated, modified, and deleted since commit X" would be supported by `--name-only`, run from any commit you'd like to look back from:

```
$ git diff <commit X SHA> --name-only
file_one
file_two
file_three
```